# Line gets overwritten instead of continuing on same line

Tags: bash, bashrc

I have a problem with the bash prompt. When I type a command that exceeds the length of the width of the screen it continues on the same line and overwrites what I have written, and then continues on line 2 afterwards.

This is my PS1:

```
PS1="\$(git_prompt) ${BIWhite}\W${Color_Off} → "
```

The variables

```
BIWhite='\e[1;97m'
Color_Off='\e[0m'
```

And then the script for git_prompt:

```
git_prompt() {
local g="$(__gitdir)"
if [ -n "$g" ]; then
    local MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT=`minutes_since_last_commit`
    if [ "$MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT" -gt 30 ]; then
        local COLOR=${BRed}
    elif [ "$MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT" -gt 10 ]; then
        local COLOR=${BIYellow}
    else
        local COLOR=${BGreen}
    fi
    local SINCE_LAST_COMMIT="${COLOR}$(minutes_since_last_commit)m${Color_Off}"
    # The __git_ps1 function inserts the current git branch where %s is
    local GIT_PROMPT=`__git_ps1 "(%s|${SINCE_LAST_COMMIT})"`
    echo ${GIT_PROMPT}
fi}
```

Appreciate all help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Characters that doesn't move the cursor has to be enclosed between `\[` and `\]` in PS1, otherwise bash thinks the prompt is longer than it actually is. And due to the way this variable is used, you can't have a function emmiting colored text as you can't escape it properly.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053 for more explanation.